# Calling a "static function" of a generic type in Scala

Tags: scala, generics

I am trying to represent pieces of another language in Scala. I would like all classes to have a custom String value representing their type. When it comes to a container class, I am having trouble.

How can I grab the `typeName` based on the generic parameter of `MyContainerClass[T <: MyType]`?

```
object MyLang {

  trait MyType {
    protected val typeName: String
  }

  class MyString(val underlying: String) extends MyType {
    protected val typeName = "mystring"
  }

  class MyInt(val underlying: Int) extends MyType {
    protected val typeName = "myint"
  }

  class MyContainerClass[T <: MyType](val underlying: Seq[T]) extends MyType {
    // LINE THAT OBVIOUSLY DOESN'T WORK
    val typeName = T.typeName + "[]"
  }
}
```

My first thought was to grab an element of `underlying` and call `typeName` on it, but what if `Seq[T]` is `Nil`?

My second thought was to create a 0 argument constructor for all classes extending `MyType`, so that I could call `new T().typeName` but this doesn't seems messy, and there is no way to enforce all subtypes of type to contain a constructor with a specific signature.

From here I found Manifests and TypeTags. I see how they are related to my problem, but fail to see how they would help me construct a solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of thing is usually done with type classes:

```
trait TypeName[T] {
  def typeName: String
}

implicit object MyString extends TypeName[MyString] {
  def typeName = "mystring"
}

implicit object MyInt extends TypeName[MyInt] {
  def typeName = "myint"
}

class MyString(val underlying: String) extends MyType {
  val typeName = MyString.typeName
}
class  MyInt(val underlying: Int) extends MyType {
  val typeName = MyInt.typeName
}

class MyContainerClass[T <: MyType : TypeName](
  val underlying: Seq[T]
) extends MyType {
  val typeName = implicitly[TypeName[T]].typeName + "[]"
}
```

The idea is that whenever `MyContainerClass` is created, a corresponding instance of `TypeName` is looked up and implicitly passed to the constructor, so you can access it there and retrieve the name.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Dima's answer is great and I was actually writing the same code, but he beat me to it. So I'll offer an alternative solution. If you are OK with using real class names:

```
import scala.reflect._

object MyLang {

  trait MyType {
    val typeName = this.getClass.getName
  }

  class MyString(val underlying: String) extends MyType

  class MyInt(val underlying: Int) extends MyType

  class MyContainerClass[T <: MyType](val underlying: Seq[T])
    (implicit tag: ClassTag[T])
    extends MyType {
    override val typeName = s"${getClass.getName}[${tag.runtimeClass.getName}]"
  }
}
```

Here is what it prints:

```
scala> new MyLang.MyContainerClass(Seq(new MyLang.MyString("abc"))).typeName

res0: String = MyLang$MyContainerClass[MyLang$MyString]
```

You could even define `typeName` as a tuple `(parent class, child class)` or any other non-string datatype that will contain `java.lang.Class[_]`.

The problem is actually that Scala doesn't let you override **static methods** as it doesn't have them. You can simulate them with `object` methods to some degree.

In your case you are trying to use an **instance** variable `typeName` but you can't get it from a class since it's not an instance. In such case you need some place to hold this value as in @Dima's answer - object that you implicitly lookup based on type. The disadvantage is that you have to create them for each type.

Comment: You can just do `tag.toString`. This is really the same solution as mine, actually: `ClassTag` is playing the role of type class. The "pro" is that it is already defined for every class, the "con", of course, that you can't customize the names.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for only the minimal implementation of the accepted answer, it's only necessary to define some trait `Y[T]`, a class `Z`, and an implicit object `Z` that extends `Y`:

```
object TypeClassTest {
    trait X

    trait Y[T] {
        def t: T
    }

    // Class with "static" method `t`
    class Z extends X

    // "static" method defined
    implicit object Z extends Y[String] {
        override def t = "t"
    }

    // Using 'static' method of the generic type
    class A[T <: X : Y](underlying: T) {
        val t: T = implicitly[Y[T]].t
    }
}
```